# Generate result report testing with xunit using .NET core

Tags: jenkins, asp.net-core, continuous-integration, xunit, xunit.net

I have a project ASP.NET core which I integrate unit test with xUnit , Everything work fine but I want to genrate xml report test to integrate in jenkins . 
Any help please :)

My project.json is :

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "testRunner": "xunit",
  "dependencies": {
    "xunit": "2.2.0-beta2-build3300",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": "1.1.0",
    "dotnet-test-xunit": "2.2.0-preview2-build1029"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "dependencies": {
      }
    }
  },
  "runtimes": {
    "ubuntu.16.04-x64": {},
    "win10-x64": {},
    "debian.8-x64": {},
    "win81-x64": {}
  }
```

}

I'm using the plugin xunit jenkins to display my result test .
If their are another way tell me .

Comment: Is your xUnit framework is generating xml reports for the tests or not?

Comment: I don't know how make xUnit generate xml reports this is my question in .NET core

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the solution , just add `-xml ./path/out.xml` .
It seems like this :

> dotnet test ./WebApi.Tests/ -xml ./WebApi.Tests/out.xml

Comment: how did you find this switch?  it appears to be undocumented?  when you do a dotnet test --help it doesn't give you any "help" about outputting results.

Comment: I finded in another issue in github by luck . Yes It's not documented unfortunately

Comment: The support for -xml switch has been dropped in more recent versions of msbuild https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/3114 although you can now output to trx using the --logger:trx switch (as described https://github.com/dotnet/cli/pull/5181), but I'm now unsure how to get that showing in Jenkins

Comment: One way to do it: add " --logger=trx" to the "dotnet test" command and then use the build step "Process xUnit test result report" from the "xUnit plugin". Use the option "MSTest-Version N/A (default) Pattern" and set pattern to "**/*.trx".

Comment: This is the answer!

Answer (score 7):

Old thread but can be useful.
In `.Net Core 3.1` you can use `--logger html` to get a read friendly report.
`dotnet test --logger html`

Using:

```
.Net Core 3.1,
Xunit 2.4.1
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue in .NET Core 2.0 and `dotnet test` does not have a -xml switch. So, I relied on a custom logger to do the job:

1. [add NunitXml.TestLogger](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnitXml.TestLogger) package to the test project
2. Run tests using this logger:

   ```
   dotnet test "project.csproj" --no-build --verbosity normal --logger:"nunit;LogFilePath=xunit_results.xml"
   ```

The output is compatible with NUnit results and be used to generate fancy reports like those obtained using [ReportUnit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ReportUnit/).

Comment: The result obtained using that method is null.
This returns to me :
<test-run id="2" duration="0" testcasecount="0" total="0" passed="0" failed="0" inconclusive="0" skipped="0" result="Passed" start-time="2019-07-24T 23:07:55Z" end-time="2019-07-24T 23:08:15Z"/>